# EF multi-context with a plugin-style system. How to apply migrations at runtime?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have a web application which is supposed to be composed as a series of plugins into a core infrastructure. A plugin is a compiled CLR dll + some content files which will be put in a certain location. I'm using Autofac to scan and register types out of the assembly, and some fancy routing to serve controllers and assets from there. But, since each plugin assembly can contain a DbContext (by convention each will use its own database), I can't quite figure out what to do there.

Now I've found a lot of stuff around how to use multiple contexts but it all requires knowing what these will be *at development time*. My application does not know what contexts will be used until runtime.

What I'm looking for ideally is would like is some way to do

```
ApplyMigrations<MyDbContext, MyDbConfiguration>();
```

Though I would also somehow have to provide an ordered set of migrations to apply (if using explicit migrations).

Where I'm stumbling currently is the standard

```
Database.SetInitializer(...)
```

since it is a static singleton and each dbcontext in my system has its own initializer.

Comment: Have you thought about loading each plugin in a separate app domain? It probably makes sense for you to do this anyway and its likely to get around this.

Comment: @LukeMcGregor but this is a web application and IIS manages app domains so how do I handle that?

Comment: I don't think there's any issue creating app domains in a web app, a project I worked on recently had a plugin system which used app domains. We used them in webapps and services with no issue.

Comment: I see, I've never spawned my own appdomain but that sounds promising. You don't happent o have nay sample code by any chance, do you?

Comment: @LukeMcGregor so I've been reading up on it, and I'm not exactly sure what you're suggesting anymore - are you recommending each plugin running a full asp.net context in its own appdomain? In that case how do you know where to route a request? Are we talking about loading *only* the EF stuff into a separate AppDomain, in that case how do you communicate between these? Do all entities have to inherit from `MarshalByRef`?

Comment: I personally would run the whole plugin in an app domain but wouldn't put the actual render loop in there, if you do have render code in there it will be a bit of a pain. Around marshallByRef, you will want to use that when you are passing functionality between classes (like an object with methods on it) you should minimise this and opt for using [Serializable] POCOs for communitations

Comment: in your case you *could* just run the EF stuff in the separate appdomain but that feels like a hack

Comment: Isn't a solution to call `SetInitializer` within the DbContext constructor?

Comment: @jjj `SetInitializer` is a static method isn't it?

Comment: If each plugin can call its own `SetInitializer` within its own DbContext constructor, that would work wouldn't it? Though multiple threads could cause strange behavior. Maybe `SetInitializer` and an explicit call to `dbContext.Database.Initialize()` in a static constructor for each dbcontext? Though, I have no idea if multiple static constructors could be running at once.

Comment: What do you mean it's own `SetInitializer`? There is only one globally static `SetInitializer` method

Comment: My first sentence was referring to what's done in the first answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190310/multiple-dbcontext-multiple-database-setinitializer)

Comment: @jjj So what benefit would putting it in the constructor have? It's not like there is anything special about the constructor, and `Database` is not scoped to the DbContext.

Comment: Isn't your concern about making sure each `DbContext` is initialized with its own `IDatabaseInitializer` in order to perform migrations?

Comment: So, am I right to understand that you have black boxed plug-ins doing their own db initializing? If so, you are swimming upstream. There are many work arounds but need more info. What events would cause the plug-ins to change their Context Models?

Comment: @DaveAlperovich  a plugin update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, of all `SetInitializer` stores the `IDatabaseInitializer` objects in a dictionary with the context Type as key, so theoretically multiple calls of `SetInitializer` should work fine.

On the other hand, if that doesn't work, another option is to explicitly perform initialization:

```
class YourContext : DbContext
{
    static YourContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<YourContext>(YourMigratingDatabaseInitializer);
        using (var context = new YourContext())
        {
            context.Database.Initialize(false);
        }
    }

    public YourContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<YourContext>(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: ooooh, I forgot about the type parameter, holy cow. Ok, will have to try this tomorrow. Sounds like it might work

Comment: Btw, usually you don't need to specify the type parameter because it is inferred from the initializer type

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps write an interface for bootstrapping a plugin, so IPluginBootstrapper - from here you could pass in a ContainerBuilder to add to a collection of services that the plugin provides, or return a built Container that the plugin builds and combine it on the host. In this way, you're pushing the responsibility of the all the DB seed/migration work into each plugin - so when you drop in a new dll, when it's bootstrapped it can run it's own upgrade path.

Another alternative, perhaps you can have a configuration section which defines a pair of types, so Tuple and tell Autofac to find all pairs of these in the plugins directory, and then call SetInitializer with what is resolved?

Comment: yes that is exactly what I'm doing already, the problem is how exactly to trigger migration when `Database.SetInitializer` is static

Comment: I think jjj has it - I can't forsee any problem with calling a Database.SetInitializer from the plugin during the initialization

Comment: Have attempted a simple demo to try this out, it seems that setting the initialization/migrations within each plugin should work. Demo at https://github.com/leonio/StackOverflow.MultiMigrations